# Fiction book about a rich girl living in a city above the criminal/poor city and ventures into the city

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

I read this book in 2014-2015 about this girl that was raised in a rich family, or royal family. She lives in the "new" city above a post apocalyptic city where the criminals and poor live. I think that one of the ways to get into the upper city was to ride a gondola type thing.

She ventures into the lower city were she meets a boy and they become friends and eventually fall in love. I remember her getting caught by her family and her memories are erased(?) The book was post-apocalyptic with new technology in the upper city.

I think I might be mixing up two different books, but I could swear that this was just one book.

Answer (score 4):

Could this be [*Mystic City*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/13411245-mystic-city) by Theo Lawrence?

> Aria Rose, youngest scion of one of Mystic City's two ruling rival
> families, finds herself betrothed to Thomas Foster, the son of her
> parents' sworn enemies. The union of the two will end the
> generations-long political feud - and unite all those living in the
> Aeries, the privileged upper reaches of the city, against the banished
> mystics who dwell below in the Depths.
>
> But Aria doesn't remember falling in love with Thomas; in fact, she
> wakes one day with huge gaps in her memory. And she can't conceive why
> her parents would have agreed to unite with the Fosters in the first
> place.
>
> Only when Aria meets Hunter, a gorgeous rebel mystic from the Depths,
> does she start to have glimmers of recollection - and to understand
> that he holds the key to unlocking her past. The choices she makes can
> save or doom the city - including herself.
>
> [image]

Comment: There's mention of gondolas in [this review](http://scififanletter.blogspot.com/2015/09/book-review-mystic-city-by-theo-lawrence.html)

Comment: How common a theme this is -- I am sure almost all cultures have stories like these. I recall walking in Manhattan and foolishly deciding (with another person) to walk through an alleyway -- suddenly there were at least a dozen loiterers around. Nothing happened but I was surprised. There are so many dangerous places close to affluent ones and I am sure this was the case even thousands of years ago. The idea also of somehow not being able to convince, say, the palace guards that you are the prince whose clothing had been exchanged with that of a beggar -- an old story also I am sure.

Answer (score 1):

Very late to the party here, it likely is *Mystic City*, but there was a book I read before going to collage called [*Legend* by Marie Lu](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29863662-legend), this has a similar story to what you described:

> What was once the western United States is now home to the Republic, a nation perpetually at war with its neighbors.
>
> Born into an elite family in one of the Republic's wealthiest districts, fifteen-year-old June is a prodigy being groomed for success in the Republic's highest military circles.
>
> Born into the slums, fifteen-year-old Day is the country's most wanted criminal. But his motives may not be as malicious as they seem.
>
> From very different worlds, June and Day have no reason to cross paths - until the day June's brother, Metias, is murdered and Day becomes the prime suspect.
>
> Caught in the ultimate game of cat and mouse, Day is in a race for his family's survival, while June seeks to avenge Metias's death. But in a shocking turn of events, the two uncover the truth of what has really brought them together, and the sinister lengths their country will go to keep its secrets.

Comment: Hi. It would be great if you could expand this answer a bit to more clearly explain how _Legend_ is similar to the book described by the OP.